# Omission du /l/ de « plus »

Tags: prononciation, négation, registre-familier

Selon ce podcast, on ne prononce pas soigneusement le /l/ du mot plus (au sens négatif) dans le registre familier; donc on entend parfois /py/.

Est-ce vrai partout ? Je ne crois pas que je l'aie entendu comme ça, mais peut-être que je n'écoutais pas bien jusqu'à maintenant.

> http://www.podcastfrancaisfacile.com/podcast/2008/11/bonjour-et-bienvenue-sur-podcastfrancaisfacilecom-aujourdhui-nous-allons-vois-quand-est-ce-quon-prononceply-ouplys.html

Le wiktionnaire dit qu'on le prononce comme ça dans le registre populaire au Québec, mais le podcast concerne le français de l'Hexagone, si je ne me trompe pas.

Answer (score 3):

C'est effectivement une des réalisations classiques en français populaire de France dans le même registre où *arbre* est réalisé [aʁb] et *ministre* [minis].

> Il n'y a plus d'arbres, M. le ministre.
>   [ja py daʁb msjø lminis]

Ce n'est sans doute pas la première réalisation à retenir de la leçon en question, mais c'est un point qui vous permettra de reconnaître ces variantes qui pourraient être surprenantes sinon.

Comment: ca reste très très populaire selon moi, je ne l'ai jamais entendu prononcer tel quel que dans de très rares cas, d'autant qu'à l'oral on peut, dans la plupart des cas, plus facilement encore le distinguer du "plus" contraire de moins en prononcant le "s" de celui-ci.

Answer (score 2):

Je ne peux pas me prononcer pour le reste du monde, mais je peux confirmer l'usage du /py/ au moins au Québec. Jamais je n'ai entendu /ply/ dans un contexte familier ou très rarement même au travail ou à l'université.
Le seul contexte auquel j'arrive à penser en ce moment qui justifierait l'emploi du /ply/ est lors d'une présentation ou conférence, bref devant un public minimalement professionnel.
Je parle évidemment de la forme négative du mot, petite précision.

Par contre je suis étonné que tu sois dans une situation contraire à la mienne. Je communique pourtant avec des européens plusieurs heures par jour et ce depuis plusieurs années sur des jeux et j'ai toujours utilisé "pu" pour mieux me faire comprendre à l'écrit sans avoir à écrire la négation et ça a toujours bien marché. J'admets tout de même que la plupart de ces personnes que j'ai côtoyées préfèrent utiliser "plu" ou "plus" (et ce sans la négation!) même si quelques uns (heureusement pour moi) acceptent le "pu" dans leur vocabulaire.